# Постраничный вывод данных для печати mysql, PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Друзья, подскажите: из базы выгружаются данные на страницу. Необходимо реализовать постраничную печать, чтобы не смещалась информация с блока. Пример:

Информация блока один:
какой-то текст
конец блока
---------------------
Информация блока два:
какой-то текст
конец блока
---------------------
Попробовала использовать `<br style="page-break-after: always">`  - не получается(( Печать так и идет со смещением

Answer (score 1):

Сильно зависит от браузера, в Хроме все ругаются на печать.
Сам мучаюсь с этим. Общие советы: все блоки, внутри печатаемого должны быть inline/inline-block/table, т.е. никаких float;
пропишите стили для печати:

```
@media print{
    .printable{
        page-break-after: always !important;
    }
}
```